# curl simple form, why session false

Tags: php, curl

i tried many tutorials but all failed, i know for an experienced user it might be obvious, thx anyway.

there is the simple form:
https://www.shab.ch/shabforms/COMMON/application/applicationGrid.jsp?template=1&view=2&page=/COMMON/search/searchForm.jsp?MODE=SHAB

here is my script which returns only the empty form instead of my POST search:
(i used tamper-data to get the Post-variables, i also use https)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.shab.ch/shabforms/COMMON/application/applicationGrid.jsp?template=1&view=2&page=/COMMON/search/searchForm.jsp?MODE=SHAB');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'KEYWORDS=&NOTICE_NR=&TIMESPAN=TODAY&STAT_TM_1=&STAT_TM_2=&SELTYPE=HR&TYPE_CD_AW=&TYPE_CD_AN=&TYPE_CD_BL=&TYPE_CD_VM=&TYPE_CD_HR=HR01&LEGAL_FORM_NR_HR=&FIRM_ID_HR=&HR_CANTON_AG=ON&HR_CANTON_BE=ON&TYPE_CD_IS=&TYPE_CD_KK=&YN_KK=&TYPE_CD_IP=&TYPE_CD_NA=&YN_NA=&TYPE_CD_SB=&YN_SB=&TYPE_CD_SR=&FIRM_NAME_TX_UP=&FIRM_CITY_TX_UP=&command=Recherchieren');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,"https://www.shab.ch/shabforms/COMMON/application/applicationGrid.jsp?template=1&view=2&page=/COMMON/search/searchForm.jsp%3Fcategory%3DHR"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
```

This has **strangely** been written into my_cookies.txt

```
www.shab.ch FALSE   /shabforms  FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  E884A3B4187C68253CEEBCD58E7E934E
www.shab.ch FALSE   /   FALSE   1287673522  BC_HA_C30B29681466613B  131BDF
```

What is wrong? :)

UPDATE:
Ok, i got the error. it was related to the post-url. the script on the website seems to do the process by ajax,... without changing the url to send (i could not even find the correct url in tamper data!!). 
Fortunately i could figure that out, its "shabforms/servlet/web/DocumentSearch".

Now it works, thx

Comment: Try using the [cur_errno()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) and [curl_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) functions to see if any cURL errors happened on the handle. My guess is that SSL is not setup correctly for your cURL.

Comment: hi, thx for the hint. i included them and there was no error appearing. i 've no clue why the form does not accept my post-values indeed. :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was related to the post-url. the script on the website seems to do the process by ajax,... without changing the url to send (i could not even find the correct url in tamper data!!). Fortunately i could figure that out, its "shabforms/servlet/web/DocumentSearch".

Now it works, thx

Answer (score 0):

I just ran this script and got a German website saved in $result.

Maybe your curl setup needs tweeking?  Have you got it working with another site?

Comment: hi, yes i use curl regularly at hostgator shared. thx 4your concern